# Check if id exists for multiple realm models

Tags: java, android, web-services, realm

I'm working on a app who uses `Realm` database.
It is communicating with my WebAPI, where it gets `JSON` data, and converts it to object and then inserts to the `Realm`.
Now I'm in a struggle, where when user tries to update the database, it gets the same data, and therefore the data multiplies.

I have searched for same problem, and the solution would be something like this.

```
 private boolean exists(long id){
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmQuery<Articles> query = realm.where(Articles.class)
                .equalTo("id", id);
        return query.count() != 0;
```

The cons of this method is that I have up to 10 models so I should write `RealmQuery` for each one.
Is there any way to extend this method or?

Comment: For 10 models you must have different id's for each..

Comment: What exaclty is your issue, you are not able to update data..or same record is inserted multiple times..or you want to get data based on ID..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If id is marked with @PrimaryKey annotation, than object updates automatically.

**model:**

```
public class Articles extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;

    //getters and setters
}
```

**insert:**

```
Article article = getFromApi();
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(article);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: I was using different approach.
`Articles ar = realm.createObject()` , I didn't see this method `copyToRealmOrUpdate()`. Thanks for help, now it works like charm!